# CSV Writer Doubling Quotes

Tags: python, csv, delimiter, quoting

I have a string in Python: `hello, my name is "Joe"`. When I try writing using the `csv` module, I get `"hello, my name is ""Joe"""`. What I am hoping to see is `"hello, my name is "Joe""`.

Is there anyway to have the CSV writer not add double quotes when there are double quotes present?

code:

```
s = 'hello, my name is "Joe"'
with open(filename, 'w', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as f_out:
    writer = csv.writer(f_out)
    writer.writerow([s])
```

Comment: Sorry to ask u, but i've just ran ur code and didn't got this problem... the problem that I got is that my string is written with commas between the letter

Comment: @gbrennon you are right and that's because the string is also a list. try to enclose it by square brackets.

Comment: How would your desired `"hello, my name is "Joe""` be parsed correctly?  The quoted field is `"hello, my name is "` and then the `Joe""` is an error.  You must escape the quote character if it appears in the string being quoted.  Don't worry about the double quoting...when read back with the csv module the string will be correct.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `quotechar` parameter when you creating `csv.writer` ([doc](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/csv.html#csv.writer)):

```
import csv

s = 'hello, my name is "Joe"'
with open('out.csv', 'w', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as f_out:
    writer = csv.writer(f_out, quotechar="'")
    writer.writerow([s])
```

Output of the file is:

```
'hello, my name is "Joe"'
```

Comment: This is correct; however, expanding this to work with multiple columns breaks.\

Comment: @xtheking Why does it break?

Comment: ```s = 'hello, my name is "Joe"'
p = 'hey "joe", i am "david"'
with open(INGEST_UPDATE_PATH + '/out.csv', 'w', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as f_out:
    writer = csv.writer(f_out, quotechar="'")
    writer.writerow([s, p])```

Comment: result: `'hello, my name is "Joe"','hey "joe", i am "david"'
`

Comment: @xtheking seems correct to me, where's the problem?

Answer (score 4):

According to [RFC 4180](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180):
"If double-quotes are used to enclose fields, then a double-quote appearing inside a field must be escaped by preceding it with another double quote."

But if you want to change that based on your specific need, try to disable double quoting and you must define an escape character:

```py
import csv

s = ['hello, my name is "Joe"']
with open(filename, 'w', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as f_out:
    writer = csv.writer(f_out, doublequote=False, escapechar='\\')
    writer.writerow(s)
```

the output file will be like:

```
"hello, my name is \"Joe\""
```

However, I recommend using the `quotechar` parameter of `csv.writer` to change the quote character as in the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56959644/1281811) by @AndrejKesely.

Answer (score 0):

Two solutions:

Either you can use `quotechar` for changing the quote character so that it ignores the double quotes found in string. `csv.writer(f_out, quotechar="'")` will do for your case.

Or you can set `escapechar="\\"` along with the `doublequote=False`. That will put backslash before every double quote for escaping it in the string. `csv.writer(f_out, escapechar="\\", doublequote=False)`

Try both of these. I hope this will answer your question.

Answer (score -2):

```
import csv

s = ['hello, my name is \"Joe\"']
filename = "C:/Users/myself/Documents/out.csv"
with open(filename, 'w', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as f_out:
    writer = csv.writer(f_out)
    writer.writerow(s)
```